# What are the latest developments in making cross-chain SCA synchronization easier?

Tags: safe-core

Cross-chain SCA synchronization here refers to the ability of the SCA stack to synchronize any changes made on Safe contract on one chain to other chains (where the Safe contracts are deployed). For eg, changing the owners of Safe on one chain should be propagated to other chains too.

This is not only a manual process that takes time to perform (inconvenient) but can also be expensive.

I'm curious if there are any recent developments/research related to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-chain synchronization is an active area of research and interest, and we do not currently provide an official way to do so in a safe and audited way. We encourage the community to develop solutions in this regard, and have pushed this many times during various hackathons we have been sponsoring. Some projects have taken that lead such as [this one](https://ethglobal.com/showcase/xsafe-bbj01). You can check our [hackathon success guide](https://safe-global.notion.site/Safe-Hackathon-Success-Guide-26ccbd7263ab44808d8f00106f35c2d7?p=886ce51b3ab64ebbb5bbcdc559dda645&pm=s) for other projects that took that lead.

For research leads, I would suggest to look at how current cross-chain bridges work (and the security trade-offs they may imply), and how they could be leveraged to achieve this. This is definitely an interesting topic for future developments.

Hope it helps! Best, Louis

Comment: Thanks Louis :)

Answer (score 1):

I also found this project that is working on [this problem](https://twitter.com/hashialliance/status/1747304836494712901)